# Tracking memory in Visual Studio 2012 Phone express

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, memory

Is there a way to track memory usage in Vs2012 express for phone? I can't seem to find any debugger options!

Answer (score 0):

Alt + F1 opens up the App analysis: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202934(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202934%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)